# Input type file size varies in Linux/ Windows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `input type="file"` element with `size="70"` and `width="522px"`. It looks and works fine in all browsers on Windows but in Firefox on Linux the input element is bigger than 522 pixels.

Things I tried:

1. `max-width:522px` but it doesn't work (Linux).
2. setting `size="52"` and `min-width:522px;` looks fine in Linux but doesn't work on in Firefox on Windows.

What can I do to specify 522 pixels width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the browser doesn't consider the button as part of the input. So if you have something like:

```
<div style="width: 500px; overflow: hidden">
<input type="file" id="uploadfile_0" class="fileinput" style="border: 2px solid #a9a9a9; width: 100%; height: 22px;" name="uploadfile_0"/>
</div>
```

The input button browse is outside the parent, and I don't think there is an easy solution to this.

You can read [about styling input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)  on quirksmode.org

Comment: i was wondering if there is a way i can set size="53" depending on os? but i cant use onload

Answer (score 1):

Specify only CSS `width`, like this:

```
<input type="file" style="width: 522px;" ..... />
```

Comment: <input type="file" size="70" id="uploadfile_0" class="fileinput" style="border: 2px solid #a9a9a9; width: 522px; height: 22px;" name="uploadfile_0"/>

This is my element.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I've ever seen file input fields styled is through a trick where the field is actually on top of an image and the field is given zero opacity.

Answer (score 0):

```
function inFil() {
    var inFil = document.getElementById("inFil");
    var iSize = inFil.files[0].size;
    alert(iSize);
   // where inFil is existing html tag <input type="button" id="inFil" >
}
```

Works with Firefox, but does not works with IE8, others not tested.